# Python implementation of the Kernel Based object tracking algorithm?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I want to do some experiments for comparing my algorithm and Kernel-Based method. Does anyone know of a complete Python implementation of the Kernel-based?
Here is the [document](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1195991)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a pure python implementation then it seems difficult to find such code.

However, there is a [`C++` implementation of the algorithm](https://github.com/gpsinghsandhu/Kernel-Based-Object-Tracking) and C/C++ library functions [can be called from python](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) by writing a `ctypes` wrapper. This way you can use this algorithm completely in python.